# How to align Joomla user profile fields Horizontally?

Tags: joomla

I am building a website using Joomla 3. , i am enabled the user- profile plugin for additional 3 fields, that fields displaying vertically in my registration form, but i want to display horizontally which means side by side,..

How can i make this? any idea please?

Comment: Have you tried some CSS?

Comment: @Mu Muthukumar Could I see your site?

Comment: sorry i have my site locally..? i tried CSS lot .but still i can't

Comment: Well we can't really help as we have no visual to guide you from

Comment: Did you make a detailed override or your use case rather than using the default behavior?

Comment: @Elin not make a detailed override, just simple override only..

Comment: Just make your override include placement for each individual field rather than looping through the fields (which is only needed when you don't know what the fields are).  Create the layout with the css classes and ids you need to get the appearance you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to find another extension/plugin for your site which will allow you more options. If you are not able to fix this using CSS (which you should be able to doing it the correct way I believe) you should check out the extensions here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management

This is an extension I have used myself and it works very well:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/25378

Another solution could be to use another template and work the CSS on that template.

Comment: I am using joomla's default beez3 template only

Comment: This makes no sense.   Changing a layout in Joomla is simple there is no reason to add an extension to change a layout.

Comment: @Elin I didnt say that an extension is needed to change a layout. I mentioned to change to another extension which may have more options and the layout or maybe with another extension it can be easier to work the CSS.

Comment: @MONZTAAA Thanks for answering a Joomla question. Did you know that we are getting really close to a dedicated Joomla site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla? Commit and help us get the beta site launched!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution without using a template override or attempt to over power any existing CSS already attached via the template would be to leverage the included Bootstrap library and use JavaScript to add the class 'form-horizontal' to the form in question.